# Is there any other way to insert data in BigQuery via API apart from via streaming data

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any other way to insert data in BigQuery  via API apart from via streaming data i.e. Table.insetAll

```
InsertAllResponse response = bigquery.insertAll(InsertAllRequest.newBuilder(tableId)
    .addRow("rowId", rowContent)
    .build())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#introduction), you also have 2 other possibilites:

> Loading from Google Cloud Storage, BigTable, DataStore

Just run a [job.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) method from the [job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) resource and set as metadata the field [configuration.load.sourceUri](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.sourceUris).

In the Python Client, this is done in the method [LoadTableFromStorageJob](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py#L528).

You can therefore just send your files to GCS for instance and then have an API call to bring the files to BigQuery.

> Media Upload

This is also a [job.load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request) operation but this time the HTTP request also carries binaries from a file in your machine. So you can pretty much send any file that you have in your disk with this request (given the format is accepted by BQ).

In Python, this is done in the resource table [Table.upload_from_file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/table.py#L1029).